# Real time get all the items of a user from their shopping cart in Solr

Tags: solr, solrj

I have a Solr shopping cart collection.

How to resolve the problem that a user adds a few items into the shopping cart and immediately view the cart to check all the items ? Right now I have to softcommit it every time an item added into the cart but that would be too many softcommits with multiple users adding items at the same time. A short softcommit timer in the config only would not work because the user may click on the cart button right after adding items, and not seeing that newly added.

What is the common way to resolve this problem with Solr ? For a few other similar situations I could use the real-time get to get around it but for a shopping cart, a user really wants to see all their items in it.

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you're actually using Solr to store that kind of information? That would probably be better suited for a session or for a regular RDBMS. Doing softcommits / NRT is the way to do this if you're locked in to Solr - do soft commits explicitly after adding the document. Are you sure there would be "too many softcommits", or are you just guessing?

Comment: ya its too many that solr throws exception back on the softcommit. I had to do the infinite loop with try catch block inside until the softcommit is successful.  Imagine 100 concurrent users adding the item at the same time and the code soft commmits it at the same time. Dont know how to do it with NRT, this cart page returns a list of all items in the cart and not a single item detail so NRTGet  would not help.

Comment: Was thinking of 100 MS soft commit in config and then make the adding cart action in Ajax in 100 MS or more regardless of the how fast server returns the call, just sleep a bit more to make it 100 MS. Is it better ?